# Rails 3.2.13: are performance issues now resolved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have looked at [What causes the extreme slowness when changing from rails 3.2.12 to 3.2.13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501354/what-causes-the-extreme-slowness-when-changing-from-rails-3-2-12-to-3-2-13/15510447#15510447) and seen various performance issues that occurred after 3.2.13 was released.

I have not found any indication that these have been resolved (without the monkeypatch in the link above).

Can anyone point me to, or confirm that 3.2.13 no longer has the specific performance issues identified shortly after release in March?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rails 3.2.13 you download today (and at any date in the future) is the same as the originally release rails 3.2.13, warts and all. It would be very confusing if the same version number identified two different versions of the code.

A patch for this was merged into the rails 3-2-stable branch, so the next release should include it.

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I thought, but not seeing a release that contained the security fixes which I had thought were important I wondered if someone had patched .13 -- I am glad not (for reasons stated) ... but also sad there's not a new release yet.  Anyway, thanks.