# Rails dev server takes a long time to reload after codes changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I swear that this was not an issue in the past and I can't pinpoint when I think this changed.  In my local development environment if I make ANY changes to my models / controllers my server takes at least 20-30 seconds to reload and respond to requests.  This is Rails 5.2.3 and Thin 1.7.2.  I don't recall it ever being this slow before.  FYI I have `config.cache_classes = false` already which is the obvious culprit.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317048/diagnosing-the-cause-of-slow-view-rendering

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744279/rails-development-server-is-slow-and-takes-a-long-time-to-load-a-simple-page

Comment: If nothing helps, I suggest reading this article: http://brewhouse.io/blog/2015/04/27/fixing-a-slow-rails-development-server.html

Comment: The `config.assets.debug = false` looks most promising right now.  Going to try these one at a time and see if I notice a change.

Comment: Any luck finding the culprit? I have the exact same issue, the server locks for 20 -30 seconds, using Rails 5.2.2 and Puma 3.12.1. Its actually faster for me to kill and reload puma then to wait for it to sort itself out after a code change...

Comment: still not sure.  Seem to be quiting everything and restarting the computer works best ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

I've been fighting with this issue for some time and I seem to have found two solutions worth trying. I run Rails 7.0.4 and Puma 6.0.

After debugging with `rack-mini-profiler`, I noticed that `Thread::Mutex#synchronize` was very slow. ~30 seconds. So I figured lowering the number of Puma threads might help. It improved but didn't completely solve the problem for me.

To run Puma single-threaded, I put the following in my Procfile:

```
RAILS_MIN_THREADS=0 RAILS_MAX_THREADS=1 bin/rails s -p 3000
```

The problem I was experiencing seems to be more directly related to this bug in Puma 6.0.0, as discussed here: https://github.com/ElMassimo/vite_ruby/issues/299 and https://github.com/jumpstart-pro/jumpstart-pro-rails/issues/475

Downgrading to 5.6.5 completely eliminated the issue, and I was able to return to multi-threaded Puma.

Comment: Strangely enough, I encountered the same issue in Puma 6.4.0. Your approach to launching the Rails server was a tremendous help. Thank you for this!

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem with puma 6.4.0. Switching RAILS_MAX_THREADS to 1 appears to fix it. I hope they fix this in puma!