# A routing error delays home page render by 3.5 seconds in my Rails 5.0 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When rendering the homepage of my Rails 5.0 project, the page eventually loads fine but I get the following log in the rails console:

```
 Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-

5.0.0
lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
(0.0ms)
 Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0
lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within
escues/layout (3569.4ms)
```

My view is in

> site/menu.html.erb

My routes:

```
   C:\Users\verbeekr\Dev\autotrader>rails routes
Prefix Verb URI Pattern Controller#Action
  root GET  /           site#menu
```

My controller:

```
class SiteController < ApplicationController

def menu
    @events = Event.get_todays_events
end
```

end

I already tried to set this in the development.rb file:

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

Based on the recommendation in [Diagnosing the cause of slow view rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317048/diagnosing-the-cause-of-slow-view-rendering)  but that did not help