# Why is Rails + webpack + split chunking serving up slow requests on localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack-dev-server, webpacker

I have a Rails (puma) app with webpacker (webpack). I'm doing split chunking on ~40 of my pages at the routing level. When I run the app locally my requests start to slow down (see img below) after about an hour of running the server. I'm not sure why. If I kill my rails server and/or webpack dev server and restart them it still continues to be slow (If I restart my machine it'll go back to being fast. haha).

Any ideas how to fix or debug this?

```
// rails console output for this page:

@method=GET path=/invite format=html controller=HomeController action=index status=200 duration=154.88 view=154.15 db=0.00
```

[image: slow request]

Comment: Please share server logs instead of browser logs.  you might find this link helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317048/diagnosing-the-cause-of-slow-view-rendering

Comment: I think I have the same issue. The thing is, @ArsiiRasheed, there are no server logs. Sprockets files do show if you disable quiet loading, but anything loaded from `/public/packs/` does not seem to leave a log anywhere, but still loads slow. It only happens with the `webpack-dev-server` running.